# Instruments Heapshots - What does this data mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm sorry about the title.  I know it is rather poor but I wasn't sure how to word it.

I have read conflicting statements on how the Leaks instrument works.  I am trying to figure out if I have any leaks left that I need to deal with, but I am very new to memory management with iOS.

[image: Leaks - Heapshots]

My question is essentially:  Does the data in this screenshot look good or bad?  I know it isn't enough information to find specific problems for me or not but I am just confused as to whether I have a problem or not.

I have read that "Heap Growth" and "Persistent" are both things that are accumulative and are not released.  Is this correct?  The numbers in Heap Growth and Persistent both start large and get smaller each time.  Does this mean things are eventually cleaning up or does it mean that I have my memory usage constantly expanding?

Comment: Huh...I kind of expected this would be common knowledge that I just haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad.  The heapgrowth is the amount of memory your app has grown since the last time you marked the heap.  Meaning objects are being allocated but ever released.  You'll have to expand the heapshots and see which objects are being retained and work out why they are not being released.  Ideally, each time you mark the heap, the growth would be 0.

The blue bars in the leaks section also shows you have something leaking memory.

Comment: Thank you.  I will have to examine it some more then.